# TextView contents in fragment is lost after changing screen orientation

Tags: android, textview, fragment

as per title, & here's a part of my code:

```
public class ExpensesDaily extends Fragment{

    private int selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay;
    private String displaySelectedDate;
    public ExpensesDaily(){}
    TextView tvDate;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            if (savedInstanceState.getString("displaySelectedDate") != null){
                String data = savedInstanceState.getString("displaySelectedDate");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "data state saved" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tvDate = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedDate);
                tvDate.setText(data);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_daily, container, false);

        ImageButton imgBtnChangeDate = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnChangeDate);
        imgBtnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment dpf = new DatePickerFragment().newInstance();
                dpf.setCallBack(onDate);
                dpf.show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "DatePickerFragment");
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {

            displaySelectedDate = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear)
                    + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
            tvDate = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedDate);
            tvDate.setText(displaySelectedDate);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("displaySelectedDate", displaySelectedDate);
    }
}
```

after i have successfully set a value in my TextView tvDate and I change the orientation, logcat will return this error

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at ExpensesDaily.onCreate(ExpensesDaily.java:38)`

which points to this line

```
tvDate.setText(data);
```

any idea why that line triggered a nullpointerexception error?

update: following the answer by user3249477, the NPE error doesn't appear anymore. However, the textview is still not updated with the saved data.

more information: I should have informed this earlier (initially I thought it didn't make any difference to my problem), the class ExpensesDaily is a fragment inside another fragment, NavigationDrawerFragment. My project here uses the NavigationDrawer project which was automatically created when we select the NavigationDrawer project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use `getActivity` inside of a fragment's onCreate.

Instead use it when the activity is created (inside of fragment's `onActivityCreated`).

That's because the fragment can be created before the activity then the getActivity method would return null, thus the *NPE*.

Comment: i've changed my onCreate to onActivityCreated, as displayed above. now no error occurs, but the TextView doesn't display the saved data. But the toast in the line above it displays the saved data. Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through this article http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html it seems I missed the most important part in retaining objects in fragment:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Anyway at first I put the code setRetainInstance(true); in my ExpensesDaily.java, but I'll get an error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments
```

But when I put the code setRetainInstance(true); inside my onCreate() inside NavigationDrawerFragment.java, my problem was solved.

So I hope my simple adventure here would help anyone else with the same problem.